# How can I disable/remove paste special options in the right click popup menu?

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to disable or remove the paste special options from the Excel 2013 right-click popup menu and I can't find a way.

I have also removed 'Paste Options' from the Excel File->Options->Advanced->Cut Copy and Paste, but this has no effect on the right button click 'Paste Options'.

I have also tried this vba code, but it appears that the control ID has changed.

```
Sub DeactivateCollageSpecial()
  Dim Ctrl As Office.CommandBarControl
  For Each Ctrl In Application.CommandBars.FindControls(ID:=755)
   Ctrl.Enabled = False
Next Ctrl
End Sub
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this code to list all likely candidates for your Paste Special control:

```
Private Sub ListPasteControls()
    For Each Ctrl In Application.CommandBars.FindControls()
        If LCase(Ctrl.Caption) Like "*paste*" Then
            Debug.Print Ctrl.Caption & " - " & Ctrl.ID
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Which gave this output for me (duplicates removed):

```
&Paste - 6002
&Paste - 22
Paste &Special... - 21437
&Paste Table - 3624
Paste Li&nk - 1956
Paste &Special... - 755
Paste as &Hyperlink - 2787
&Paste... - 879
```

Leading me to the ID 21437. When I tried disabling those controls using your code, the context menu version of "Paste Special..." became greyed-out as desired. Looking through some of the parents of these controls, I think it should disable all sorts of cases I hadn't thought of, like right-clicking on a full row/column instead of just a cell/range - without any undesired consequences I could identify.